# How to include a JOIN after the WHERE?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to execute a statement that follows a given Prefix.

We use a certain program, it features a 'Search Folder'. Into the Search folder, I can define an SQL query. The Folder has a built-in part of the query, which I can not modify.

The built-in part is:

```
Prefix Artikelfilter: SELECT * FROM CMKAT.ART WHERE 1=1 AND
```

Now I would like to perform the following search query:

```
select * from CMKAT.ART

join CMKAT.AEZ on art.artKEYI = aez.aezartkeyi

join pro on pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi

left outer join psz on pro.prokeyi = psz.pszprokeyi

WHERE psz.pszprokeyi is null

AND pro.proetykeyi = 1;
```

Of course, the 'SELECT *...' part is redundant, but how can I get the query to work? The JOINs are after the WHERE.

I know the developers solved this issues by creating Views, and making the selection from the view, not directly in the query.

Edit:

Exception: JdbcAccess.execute failed (ORA-00904: "KVTBEZC": ungültige ID
).

```
 SQL: 
<prefix>
SELECT /* filter art */ artkeyi, artkavkeyi, artvnrs FROM art  JOIN 
kav ON art.artkavkeyi = kav.kavkeyi  JOIN kvt ON kav.kavkvtkeyi = 
kvt.kvtkeyi  JOIN kat ON kav.kavkatkeyi = kat.katkeyi  WHERE 
(artkavkeyi IN (587, 3075, 7, 8, 592)) AND

</prefix>

 1 = 0 union all select * 
from cmkat.art  join cmkat.aez on art.artkeyi = aez.aezartkeyi  join 
pro on pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi  left join psz on pro.prokeyi = 
psz.pszprokeyi  where psz.pszprokeyi is null and pro.proetykeyi = 1 
AND katkeyi = 4 AND (katspes IN (0, 3, 1, 2))/* join-dummy */ ORDER BY 
artkeyi, kvtbezc (DATABASE_EXECUTE_FAILED)
```

Comment: Well your query looks at least that it might already _run_, so what is the problem with it?

Comment: My query runs and delivers the required sets, but it won't run with the Prefix, wich I can not change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think they have an existing code where you can only add (perhaps concatenate) conditions to it.Yet Bob need other information to filter on, so he need to join on some tables

Comment: Looks like your application is adding the order-by clause automatically too, right? As `kvtbezc` isn't in the original query's projection you aren't going to be able to work around that with the union - just including a column with that name or alias in the new branch won't work either. What error did you get from the `exists` attempt? That sounds more promising from what you've shown, so maybe you didn't fix all the problems in that answer...

Comment: @AlexPoole: When I try EXISTS , I get all items.

Comment: The comment on that answer said it errored. If you're getting all rows back and it isn't filtering as you expected then the sub-query in your exists clause isn't right, but as we can't see how you transformed that broken answer we can't see what's wrong. (I'd *guess* that you put your whole new query into that clause rather than just the extra tables and a correlation...)

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: The template only allows you to select columns from ART. So there is no solution unless you want results of a query of the form `select` some columns of CMKAT `from ART` .... But your query is not of that form. PS What did "the developers" do exactly & what does it have to do with your question? What form can a solution to your question have? What does the code at the end have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'd construct the SQL this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CMKAT.ART 
WHERE 1=1 AND EXISTS (Select 1 
                      From CMKAT.AEZ, pro 
                           left outer join psz on pro.prokeyi = psz.pszprokeyi 
                      Where aez.aezartkeyi = art.artKEYI and pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi and psz.pszprokeyi is null AND pro.proetykeyi = 1
                      );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting an error (but our program is unhelpful, it just tell me that the command can not be executed).

Comment: @BobBobson check your database's log

Comment: That query has errors. First you should **not** mix implicit and explicit joins (`from CMKAT.AEZ, pro left outer join ...`) and this part ` = aez.aezprokeyi psz.pszprokeyi is null` is missing something. Did you mean `AND psz.pszprokeyi is null`? And `pro.pro.prokeyi` is an invalid column reference

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I noticed these errors and corrected them before running the query.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need right query like this:

```
If exists (SELECT 1 FROM CMKAT.ART WHERE 1=1)
  Begin
     (
     Select  * 
     From CMKAT.ART 
          Inner join CMKAT.AEZ on art.artKEYI = aez.aezartkeyi
          Inner join pro on pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi 
          Left Outer join psz on pro.prokeyi = psz.pszprokeyi 
     WHERE psz.pszprokeyi is null AND pro.proetykeyi = 1;
     )
  END
```

Comment: I can not change the prefix

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your tool allows such construction, but you could cheat it using `union all`:

```
select * from cmkat.art where 1 = 1 and 1 = 0
union all
select cmkat.art.* 
  from cmkat.art
  join cmkat.aez on art.artkeyi = aez.aezartkeyi
  join pro on pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi
  left join psz on pro.prokeyi = psz.pszprokeyi
  where psz.pszprokeyi is null and pro.proetykeyi = 1;
```

First line removes data of original query because of `1 = 0` condition so we get only data from second part of union.

Unfortunately you can obtain only columns of `art` table because your tool does not allow to change selected data. But you can change it selecting some columns from joined tables **instead** of `art` columns.

Comment: Still an error, but I will investigate in this direction. Unseen U rules! ;)

Comment: So I looked at log, it seems I can't simply void the prefix: See edit for the original question